# Why there is Different accuracy for two same trained model?

Tags: deep-learning, training, accuracy

Trained the same model twice with the same dataset, the same parameters (Epochs, Batch Size, Learning rate, etc..). But both trained model shows different train as well as test accuracy on the same dataset.
(code is same for two models)

Why both models show different accuracy?

1. Train the model

   **Test accuracy = 87.98%**
2. Again Train the model

   **Test accuracy = 67.18%**

Comment: If the training score is different then the 2nd model is not trained fully. What is the data size for both the set and what is happening in 3rd, 4th time?

Comment: Yes, the training score is different for both the trained models. Dataset size for training is 13,558 (9 class). I have tried 2 times. Let me check for the 3rd and 4th trials also.

Comment: At the 3rd time model's test accuracy: 85.68% & for 4th time: 76.38%

Comment: You could use random_state=42 when splitting the data.

Comment: If you share the code you are using it will be more easy for us to help.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the code there should be some parameter that is initialised randomly, this is usually called the random seed. It could be the different initialisation of your neural network weights that is affecting the results, or maybe the k-fold being different if done at random.
The extent of the difference between the performance suggests that you might not have enough data to reliably learn a good model, or your model is underspecified and gets stuck at different local minima. Consider, changing the learning rate and other hyperparameters and see if the effect stays.

Comment: The random seed value is selected as 2 in the code. So, there are any such criteria for the selection of random seed value?

Answer (score 0):

Often the initial training is slow, because the model is stuck in a part of parameter space with low gradients. Then it is essentially taking a random walk, until it reaches an attractor.

You can often get a better shaped loss surface by regularizing - then training is less reliant on luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Tensorflow / Keras make sure to set a random seed with:

`tf.random.set_seed(42)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).